# ctypes - references from C to python objects

Tags: python, ctypes, reference-counting

I'm using a C library from python using ctypes. There's a callback function with a void* argument I'm using as ctypes.py_object. The object pointer is given to the library when the callback is registered. However when it is no longer referenced from python code, it should be destroyed. I want it to survive until the callback function is called. How do I do that?

```
callback_t=ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.py_object)
clib.register_callback.argtypes=[callback_t, ctypes.py_object]
clib.register_callback.restype=None

class Object:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val=val

def callback(obj):
    print(obj.val)

callback_c=callback_t(callback)

def calledByOtherCode(val):
    clib.register_callback(callback_c, Object(val))
```

Comment: Could you show an example of the code you used with the callback function? This would make it much easier to show how to modify it (otherwise an answerer would have to write up an example, make some guesses as to how you're approaching it, and only then answer the question)

Comment: There's a global callback function that gets registered and unregistered a lot of times for different objects.

Comment: Can't you just keep a reference to your `Object(i)` calls in the python code so that they are not garbage collected?

Comment: @ebarr I'd prefer not to.

Answer (score 4):

You could try incrementing/decrementing the refcount manually:

```
def calledByOtherCode(val):
    o = Object(val)
    pyo = ctypes.py_object(o)
    ctypes.pythonapi.Py_IncRef(pyo)
    clib.register_callback(o)

def callback(obj):
    print(obj.val)
    pyobj = ctypes.py_object(obj)
    ctypes.pythonapi.Py_DecRef(pyobj)
```